# Bigquery not picking up a column name to join tables

Tags: google-bigquery

Why am i getting an error saying that SA2_NAME_2016 is not found when that column is indeed in table c?

select a.Avg__O_Sample_A_5G, a.Avg__O_Sample_A_All_5G, a.Avg__O_Sample_iOS_5G, a.Avg__O_Sample_iOS_All_5G,b.*, c.geomtry

from o-a-c-prd.R_A_K_SCORE_BREAKDOWN.Churn_May as a

left join

(select * from o-a-c-prd.R_A_K_SCORE_BREAKDOWN.A_K_MAY where Month = '2022-05') as b

on

a.SA2 = b.SA2_NAME_2016

JOIN

(select geometry from o-a-c-prd.R_P_Polygons.SA2_GEO_PUB_T ) as c

on

a.SA2 = c.SA2_NAME_2016

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY column available in c is geometry!! So, the error you see makes total sense

Use below instead

```
select a.Avg__O_Sample_A_5G, 
  a.Avg__O_Sample_A_All_5G, 
  a.Avg__O_Sample_iOS_5G, 
  a.Avg__O_Sample_iOS_All_5G,
  b.*, 
  c.geometry
from o-a-c-prd.R_A_K_SCORE_BREAKDOWN.Churn_May as a
left join 
  (select * from o-a-c-prd.R_A_K_SCORE_BREAKDOWN.A_K_MAY where Month = '2022-05') as b
on a.SA2 = b.SA2_NAME_2016
JOIN 
  (select SA2_NAME_2016, geometry from o-a-c-prd.R_P_Polygons.SA2_GEO_PUB_T ) as c
on a.SA2 = c.SA2_NAME_2016
```